# Add/Remove 'disabled' attribute on increment/decrement buttons when reached min-max

Tags: javascript

I am having some small issues.

I have a working javascript counter, using two `buttons` to increment / decrement the input value. The input value has different attributes, such as `step`, `max` and `min`.

I need to add a DOM Event Listener that would add a disabled attribute (`.setAttribute('disabled', ''`) to the buttons (`#increment` and `#decrement`) when it has reached max or min. Is this possible with MutationObserver?

#### Expected result:

- When the input value **is** `-10`, **decrement** button should have `disabled attribute`, and removed when it **not** `-10`.
- When the input value **is** `40`, **increment** button should have `disabled attribute`. and removed when it is **not** `40`

```js
const increment = document.getElementById("increment");
const decrement = document.getElementById("decrement");
const number = document.getElementById("number");


increment.addEventListener('click', () => {
number.stepUp(1);
})

decrement.addEventListener('click', () => {
number.stepDown(1);
})
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<button id="increment">+</button>
<input id="number" type="number" value="0" step="10" max="40" min="-10" />
<button id="decrement">-</button>
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to check for the boundaries when you increment/decrement the value and there make the button disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable or disable the buttons based on the value inside the event handlers.

```js
const increment = document.getElementById("increment");
const decrement = document.getElementById("decrement");
const number = document.getElementById("number");

function checkButtons(){
  increment.disabled = number.value >= number.max;
  decrement.disabled = number.value <= number.min;
}

increment.addEventListener('click', () => {
   number.stepUp(1);
   checkButtons();
})

decrement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  number.stepDown(1);
  checkButtons();
})
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

disabled {
  background-color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="increment">+</button>
<input id="number" type="number" value="0" step="10" max="40" min="-10" />
<button id="decrement">-</button>
```

Comment: Great answer, it works perfectly. What If I want to make it reusable, and instead of IDs, use Classes. (`querySelector('.increment')`), and I have 2 containers, with 2 buttons and 1 input field each. How can I select that specific field to start the counter?

Comment: @PopeyeIT You mean you have multiple pairs of buttons that you need to handle?

Comment: No worries hev1, I made it happen :). using `querySelectorAll` and wrapping the function in a forEach

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your event listeners like this:

```
increment.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(number.value >= number.max) return number.disabled = true;
  if(number.disabled) number.disabled = false;
  number.stepUp(1);
})

decrement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(number.value <= number.min) return number.disabled = true;
  if(number.disabled) number.disabled = false;
  number.stepDown(1);
})
```